# Animated Splash Screen showing white page

Tags: flutter, dart

i wanted to use the AnimatedSplashScreen but in my case it didnt work.
This is the AnimatedSplashScreen displayed in my app:
[image: AnimatedSplashScreen displayed in my app]

Here my SplashScreen-Class:

```dart
class SplashScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const SplashScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = AuthService().currentUser;
    String nextScreen =
        user != null ? RoutesEnum.homePage : RoutesEnum.loginPage;

    return AnimatedSplashScreen(
      duration: 1500,
      splash: Icons.home,
      nextScreen: LoginPage(),
      nextRoute: nextScreen,
      splashTransition: SplashTransition.rotationTransition,
    );}}
```

And my main.dart where the MaterialApp is created:

```dart
    void main() async {
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
      await Firebase.initializeApp();
      runApp(MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: mainTheme,
      home: const SplashScreen(),
      routes: {
        //RoutesEnum.splashScreen: (context) => const SplashScreen(),
        RoutesEnum.loginPage: (context) => LoginPage(),
        RoutesEnum.signUpPage: (context) => SignUpPage(),
        RoutesEnum.homePage: (context) => HomePage(),
      },
      ));
      }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for ypur help.

**Edit:**

This is my LoginPage:

```
class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  final authService = AuthService();

  final emailcon = TextEditingController();
  final passwordcon = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Image.asset(
                  "assets/images/Logo_ohne_Hintergrund.png",
                  color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.75),
                  colorBlendMode: BlendMode.modulate,
                ),
                addVerticalSpace(60),
                addFormEmailPassword(emailcon, passwordcon),
                addVerticalSpace(20),
                RoundButton(
                  title: "Login",
                  tapfun: () => {
                    if (emailcon.text.toString().isEmpty ||
                        passwordcon.text.toString().isEmpty)
                      {
                        toastmessage("Eingaben prüfen"),
                      }
                    else
                      {
                        authService
                            .signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                              email: emailcon.text.toString(),
                              password: passwordcon.text.toString(),
                            )
                            .then(
                              (value) => {
                                if (value)
                                  {
                                    Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(
                                      context,
                                      RoutesEnum.homePage,
                                    ),
                                  }
                              },
                            ),
                      }
                  },
                ),
                addVerticalSpace(20),
                const Text("- OR -"),
                addVerticalSpace(20),
                GoogleAuthButton(
                  style: AuthButtonStyle(
                    buttonType: AuthButtonType.icon,
                    buttonColor: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
                    borderRadius: 25,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () => {
                    authService.signInWithGoogle().then(
                          (value) => {
                            Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(
                              context,
                              RoutesEnum.homePage,
                            ),
                          },
                        ),
                  },
                ),
                addVerticalSpace(20),
                RoundButton(
                  title: "Toast",
                  tapfun: () {
                    toastmessage(
                      authService.currentUser == null
                          ? "NULL"
                          : authService.currentUser!.email.toString(),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30),
            child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  const Text(
                    "Don't have an account?",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                  TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.pushNamed(
                        context,
                        RoutesEnum.signUpPage,
                      );
                    },
                    child: const Text("Sign Up"),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you recheck `LoginPage` and `nextScreen`

Comment: What should i check there?

Comment: Is there any issue on `LoginPage` page, like overflow or something route name causing this. Can include full snippet that will reproduce the same issue

Comment: I added the LoginPage. For me there`re no errors or issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below-mentioned package:

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash

This package automatically generates iOS, Android, and Web-native code for customizing this native splash screen background colour and splash image. It supports dark mode, full screen, and platform-specific options.

Answer (score 0):

I found the mistake.
In the MaterialApp the theme-Property makes the trouble. When i remove that it works. Why is that so?

[image]